# How can I take a string of text with hyperlinks, unwrap them, and re-insert them in php?

Tags: php, twitter, hyperlink

If I have a string of text from Twitter, such as:

```
$string = "This is a link http://t.co/252351ga to follow.";
```

How can I unwrap the link, and re-insert into the original string as follows:

```
$new_string = "This is a link http://www.example.org/article/23534 to follow.";
```

Comment: Unwrap them? As in unshorten them, so you point to the real url and not the shortener?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use something like preg_replace and use a pattern to match URLs and replace the match with your own URL.

**EDIT:**
You can find a good URL regexp here:
http://flanders.co.nz/2009/11/08/a-good-url-regular-expression-repost/

Then use it as follows:

```
$string = "This is a link http://t.co/252351ga to follow.";
$pattern = ''; //the pattern from the link
$replacement = 'http://www.example.org/article/23534';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a two-part problem. First you need a regex to find and extract the URLs. It's best to use preg_replace_callback there for simplicity. (You'll find any number of nicer regexs, if you use the search.)

```
 = preg_replace_callback('#http://\S+#', "replace_url_callback", $html)
```

Second, you either use a shortened URL expansion service/API, or request the URLs yourself and check for redirects or the according meta tag in the response. (For example: http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/18/expanding-short-urls-with-php-expand_url-php-function/ -  <s>Forgot the service name I read about lately..</s> Nevermind, it's simply called "LongURL.org". Not affiliated.)